# PHPUnit database connection error

Tags: php, phpunit, oracle-call-interface, tns

Very simple-to-explain problem here (at least after struggling with it and simplifying it almost up to the absurd).

I do a connection via the OCI driver inside a file called whatever.Test.php. Just that, make a simple query, and exit. I then call the file from the browser, and the data taken from the database is properly displayed. Next step: I run PHPUnit over the same file, with the following result:

```
PHP Warning:  oci_connect(): ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified in ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use connection string in `oci_connect()`; is your environment set (`TNS_ADMIN`, `ORACLE_SID`, `ORACLE_HOME`) and the same as the environment when `whatever.Test.php` is opened through a browser?

Answer (score 0):

The final solution was a little bit obvious once I came up with it. Somehow the server could figure out what the server I was trying to connect with was, via the tnsnames.ora file somewhere, I guess. However, since the script execution doesn't trigger all the server processes this information was not reachable any more from there. So what I needed to do is to provide all the data in the oci_connect() $connection_string parameter, using the format `[//]host_name[:port][/service_name][:server_type][/instance_name]` ([check documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php)). Previously I was only giving the host_name part.

(Thanks anyway for your reply, user*).